# Summing up numbers inside while function

Tags: python, while-loop, count

The goal of the program is to ask user for input for a number of calories in given meal. Later I would like to add the numbers so that the program remembers the previous input. This is only part of the program, but later it returns back to user_input_calories so user can input calories as many times they want. Probably count_calories should not be zero. Could someone help me with that or add some references that I can take a look at?

```
start=input('Type add to add a meal:')
while start=='add' or start=='Add': 
user_input_calories=input('Enter the number of calories in the meal:')
try:
    nr1=int(user_input_calories)
    count_calories=0 
    count_calories=count_calories+nr1
except:
    print('You have finised eating for the day')
continue
```

Comment: You need a summing variable outside the loop (i.e. move count_calories). Any variable defined inside the loop will be 'reset' each time the loop runs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what Matt Clark wrote in the comment:

```
start=input('Type add to add a meal: ')
count_calories=0 # Counter outside the loop
while start.lower() == 'add':
    user_input_calories=input('Enter the number of calories in the meal (q to quit): ')
    if user_input_calories == 'q': # Added a command to end the program and count the calories
        print('You have finised eating for the day')
        print(f'You ate: {count_calories} calories')
        break
    try:
        user_input_calories = int(user_input_calories) # Try to convert to integer and add the value
        count_calories += user_input_calories
    except:
        print("You didn't enter a number")
```

Result:

```
Type add to add a meal: add
Enter the number of calories in the meal (q to quit): 100
Enter the number of calories in the meal (q to quit): 200
Enter the number of calories in the meal (q to quit): 300
Enter the number of calories in the meal (q to quit): q
You have finised eating for the day
You ate: 600 calories
```